# How to call the Seq variant of persist?

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

What is the intended usage of the `persist` method in Akka Persistence for sequences of events? I see that there's a signature like this [here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/index.html#akka.persistence.PersistentActor):

```
final def persist[A](events: Seq[A])(handler: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

but if I try to call it as in the following example

```
def receiveCommand= {
  case x ⇒
    val events = Seq(Event("1"), Event("2"))
    persist(events) {
      e ⇒ println(e) // here it gets printed "List(Event(1),Event(2))"
    }
}
```

I get printed one single event as `List(Event(1),Event(2))`. That is, I was expecting to handle each event separately and in the order they are given. But instead, it seems like in the following `persist` variant

```
final def persist[A](event: A)(handler: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

the type parameter `A` is replaced by `Seq[Event]` instead of being replaced by `Event` and calling the sequence variant. What is the expected way to use this method?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `persist[Event](events)` work?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that

```
  final def persist[A](events: Seq[A])(handler: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

takes an

```
  scala.collection.immutable.Seq
```

as argument so you have to pass in this concrete Seq type:

```
 val events: scala.collection.immutable.Seq = scala.collection.immutable.Seq("event")   
 persist(events) { event =>
     log.debug("persisted " + event) 
 }
```

Comment: So, when you write `Seq(1,2,3)` without specifying, it is actually a mutable sequence?

Comment: No. In fact it is an immutable sequence as this is the default in scala. But the problem here is that it is not typed as such. You may import scala.concurrent.immutable.Seq on top of your source file to state that all the sequences are immutable. The akka people intended to be sure that the seq must be immutable but should have choosen a different method name to prevent confusion.